# writing a text on a picture by writing bytes

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing

I code below I have image2 which  is a picture of somewhere and the image3 which is a text in a white plane (for example a "hello" written in paint.exe in default white background).

I want to show the text on the picture but the code does not succeeds. what is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;


namespace test_AlignmentOFImages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        WriteableBitmap bitmap;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           byte []pixels=new byte[480*640*4];

            for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 16 == 0)
                {
                    pixels[i] = 0xff;
                }
                else
                {
                    pixels[i] = (byte)i;
                }
                //pixels[i] = (byte)0xff;//white
            }
            int stride2 = 480 * 4;
            image2.Source = BitmapImage.Create((int)image2.Width, (int)image2.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, pixels, stride2);

            byte [] imagePixels=new byte[480*640*4];
            System.Drawing.Image img;
            //System.Drawing.Bitmap bm;
            try
            {
                //img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"E:\src\Tests\test_AlignmentOFImages\test_AlignmentOFImages\image3.jpg");
                img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"E:\src\Tests\test_AlignmentOFImages\test_AlignmentOFImages\image3.png");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); //img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            Array.Copy(ms.ToArray(), imagePixels, ms.ToArray().Length);

            byte[] imagePixels2 = new byte[480 * 640*4];
            image3.Source = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < imagePixels.Length; i+=4)
            {
                if (imagePixels[i]<0xff  )//if it is not white
                {
                    imagePixels2[i] = imagePixels[i];//blue
                    imagePixels2[i+1] = imagePixels[i+1];//green
                    imagePixels2[i+2] = imagePixels[i+2];//red
                    imagePixels2[i+3] = 0xff;//alpha
                }


            }

            image3.Source = BitmapImage.Create((int)image3.Width, (int)image3.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, imagePixels2, stride2);
        }
    }
}
```

i think that I am using false pixel format and for png or jpeg format i must use special pixel format (for example bgr24 or ...).
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

With these lines you process the pixel data and convert it to a PNG file. But you want to continue to manipulate pixel data. Not formatted PNG data.

So use `LockBits()` instead:

```
imagePixels = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

The next problem is your copy method. With the code you provided you just copy image3.png to the output, discarding any alpha channel and not considering white areas. Don't allocate a new array of pixels. It is sufficient to use the `pixels` array you defined earlier.

```
if (imagePixels[i]<0xff  )//if it is not white
```

This statement does not check if a pixel is white. It just checks if the red channel of a pixel is 255. You should check the other channels, too.